# Net::IMAP::NoResponseError: Invalid credentials (Failure)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Steps:

1. `require 'net/imap'`
2. `imap = Net::IMAP.new("imap.gmail.com", 993, true)`
3. `imap.login(email, password)`

passed email and password values, but I am getting the below error message:

> Net::IMAP::NoResponseError:  Invalid credentials (Failure)

Comment: Please make 100% sure that your credentials are working. I did the exact same thing that you described and I can login

Comment: If I use the same credentials to log in through Gmail it's working fine but if I use net/imap it's not working.

Comment: Solved...Steps to follow - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

1. Go to your Google Account
2. On the left navigation panel, click Security
3. On the bottom of the page, in the Less secure app access panel, click Turn on access.

Comment: @VDN you should add your comment as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If u came here after 30.05.2022 here is a potential solution if you get Invalid Credentials while connecting to IMAP:

As we can read here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Google could disable access for 'less secure apps' for your account if it was inactive and you cannot turn the access back on. If you have this problem, you should enable 2FA and generate a token for the application, and authenticate with it, as mentioned here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en